# Hangouts can't connect to server - Android phone

Tags: google-hangouts

I was using my Hotmail account for a very long time for hangouts and other Google services. Today I create a Gmail account on top of my existing Hotmail Google services. This is supposed to mean that the Google email is now the primary way to access all of that information. I did it and as soon as I did that, I couldn't log into Hangouts on my Nexus 5. Can someone please help me out?

I can still receive SMS with the app, just not hangout messages.
I can't use hangouts on gmail.com or other google web sites either.

I have uninstalled and reinstalled the hangouts app. Everything is up to date.

I have factory reset my phone and logged in with my Google email. Still doesn't work. I'm starting to believe it's something on the Google side of things and not anything to do with my phone.

Answer (score 1):

This problem seems to have resolved itself over night.
This is only speculation, but my guess would be that some of the processing involved in converting a non-gmail Google account to a gmail Google account happens overnight. I woke up this morning and everything seems to be working perfectly again.